# General vector space theory developed without matrix-theory.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Since vector spaces can exist regardless of a matrix I wanted to see if we could do all the proofs for the general vector-spaces without using theory for matrices. Then it was only two proofs of the general vector spaces in my book that uses the theory of matrices. One was the rank-nullity theorem and the other one I will write below. On wikipedia there is a proof for the rank-nullity theorem where they don't consider a matrix, so that is ok, but I have the theorem below also:

> If a vector space V has a basis $\beta=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$, then any set
>   in V containing more than n vectors must be linerly dependent.

The sad thing is that in this proof they used theory about matrices from an earlier chapter. However let's say you didn't even know about matrices. Now is it possible to prove this without using matrix-theory?

**NOTE:**
Here are some things we may **not use** in proving this, because these properties are only proved after the theorem above is proved.

1. If a vector space V has a basis of n vectors, then every basis of V must consist of exactly n vectors.
2. If V has dimension p, then any p linerly independent vectors is a basis for V. And if p elements span V, then they are automatically a basis.

Basically what we **can use** are these things developed before the theorem:

1.The definition of the general vector space with 10 properties.

2.Definition of a subspace.

3. The definition of linear independence.
4. The definiton of a basis, which says that the vectors in the basis are linearly 
   independent and every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of them.
5. Then unique representation of each vector in the vector space in terms of its scalar infront of each basis vector.

Is it then possible to prove the theorem above by this?, or would the theory of general vector spaces not be able to exist without matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using matrices is the natural way to prove this: there is no need. It probably doesn't hurt if the theory is available though. In any case, below is a direct argument that shows that any two basis of $V$  have the same number of elements (at least in the finite-dimensional case).

Suppose that $\beta=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ is a basis, and that $\gamma=\{c_1,\ldots,c_m\}$ is another one. Assume $n\leq m$ (no loss of generality, since we can exchange roles if we want).

Then there exist coefficients such that 
$$
c_1=\alpha_1b_1+\cdots+\alpha_nb_n.
$$
At least one of the coefficients is nonzero, since $c_1\ne0$. By reordering if needed, we can assume $\alpha_1\ne0$. Then 
$$
b_1=\frac1{\alpha_1}c_1-\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}b_2-\cdots-\frac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_1}b_n.
$$
Since we can obtain $b_1$ from $c_1$ and $b_2,\ldots,b_n$, the set $\{c_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ spans $V$. So there exist coefficients such that
$$
c_2=\delta_1c_1+\delta_2b_2+\cdots+\delta_nb_n.
$$
If $\delta_2=\cdots=\delta_n=0$, we get $c_2=\delta_1c_1$, which is a contradiction unless $\delta_1$ (because $c_1,c_2$ are linearly independent); but this would make all the $\delta_j$ equal to zero and this is not true as $c_2\ne0$. So at least one of $\delta_2,\ldots,\delta_n$ is nonzero. After reordering the $b_j$ is necessary, we may assume that $\delta_2\ne0$. So
$$
b_2=-\frac{\delta_1}{\delta_2}c_1+\frac1{\delta_2}c_2-\frac{\delta_3}{\delta_2}b_3-\cdots-\frac{\delta_n}{\delta_2}b_n.
$$
We deduce that $\{c_1,c_2,b_3,\ldots,b_n\}$ spans $V$.

If we repeat the idea above we will get that $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,b_4,\ldots,b_n\}$ spans $V$, and eventually we will get that $\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\}$ spans $V$. But then, if $m>n$, we get that $c_{n+1}$ is a linear combination of $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, contradicting the fact that $\{c_1\ldots,c_m\}$ is linearly independent. So $m=n$.

Comment: I forgot to thank you for this, thanks, it is interesting to see that vector spaces can indeed be formed entirely without matrices?

Answer (score 0):

the proof is still easy. consider $x_1, \cdots , x_m$ where $m>n$. Take $a_i$ s.t. $\sum a_ix_i=0$. Then uniquely it follows...

and what comes after the dots? Right, terms with double indices (and basis vectors), but such things we like to call matrices. Anyways, you just see and observe, that matrices are an easier way to write such proofs down.

Comment: Yeah, I see that with doing this then in order to get to finish, we have to use the fact that: "If we have a linear systems of equations, where every equation equals zero, and if we have more variables than equations, then a non-trivial solution exist". Is it not possible to prove this without using that kind of theory?